# Getting code: "auth/network-request-failed" in Chrome Extension

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I am getting following exception, while calling **signInWithEmailAndPassword** method of firebase:
[image]

Following is the code of my content.js file:

```
var config = {

    apiKey: "******",
    authDomain: "******",
    databaseURL: "******",
    projectId: "******",
    storageBucket: "******",
    messagingSenderId: "******"   
};

var firebase_email = "firebase_email"; var firebase_password = "firebase_password";

firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(firebase_email, firebase_password)
.then((result) => console.log('Signin result', result))
.catch(function (error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    if (errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
        alert("Wrong password for Firebase API in config.");
    } else {
        console.log(errorMessage);
    }
    console.log(error);
});
```

And following is the code of my **manifest.json** file:

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Firebase Auth in Chrome Extension Sample",
  "description": "This sample shows how to authorize Firebase in a Chrome extension using a Google account.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [      
      "https://some websitename*",
    ],
    "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "firebase.js", "content.js"]
  }],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "My Extension!"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "https://*/*",
    "activeTab",
    "background",
    "storage"
  ],

  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'" 
}
```

Strange, the same code works when I run it as JavaScript Application, see the below screenshot:
[image]

I tried various things, but could not identify the reason behind this.
Please guide me in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Check the network panel in devtools and compare the requests (their headers, responses) made in the content script and the localhost page.

Comment: I have checked that, there is only difference in Response Headers. I chrome Extension it returns only 2 headers: access-control-allow-origin: https://website.com,  
access-control-expose-headers: date,content-encoding,server,content-length

Comment: with 400 status code.

Comment: Did you whitelist your extension in the "Authentication" -> "Sign-in method" -> "Authorized domains" section of your firebase project?  Like this: chrome-extension://CHROME_EXTENSION_ID  Also, you may need https://apis.google.com in your CSP.

Comment: yes, I have added the website name in that section, still I get this error. This works well from normal javascript app, but throws error in chrome extension.